# CallKit not dialing anything

Tags: swift, callkit

Based on various sources, I have implemented CallKit like below, but my app is not dialing. Any ideas? No errors are being reported.

Here is what I have:

```
let provider = CXProvider(configuration: CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App"))
provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
let controller = CXCallController()
let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "5555555555")))
self.controller.request(self.transaction, completion: { error in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    }
```

My Extension:

```
extension ViewController : CXProviderDelegate {
    
    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
    }
    
    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
    }
    
    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you make a `CXStartCallAction` transaction and it doesn't fail, then the CallKit framework will call the following `CXProviderDelegate` function:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction)
{
    action.fullfill()
}
```

So, if you implement this method, the outgoing call will start as soon as you call `action.fullfill()`.